# How to configure Services with Spring Data JPA repositories with spring Java Configuration

Tags: spring, jpa-2.0, spring-data

I am trying to figure out how to get a hold of the OrderRepository so that I can pass it into the constructor of the OrderServiceImpl using Spring's java configuration (I already know how to do it with xml configuration).

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.sample.app")
@EnableJpaRepositories("com.sample.app")
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class AppConfig 
{

    @Bean
    public OrderService orderService()
    {
        return new OrderServiceImpl(orderRepository());
    }

    @Bean
    public OrderRepository orderRepository()
    {
        return ??? What goes here ???
    }
    ...
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.sample.app")
@EnableJpaRepositories("com.sample.app")
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class AppConfig {

    @Autowired
    private OrderRepository orderRepository;

    @Bean
    public OrderService orderService() {
        return new OrderServiceImpl(orderRepository);
    }

}
```

Something like that should work. Or simply put a field inside your `OrderServiceImpl` which is annotated with `@Autowired` and remove the constructor which takes an `orderRepository`. Or rely on component-scanning and remove the `@Bean` methods all together.

You have a component-scan and @Bean method, you might run into duplicate instances of your service that way (if it is annotated with `@Service`).